# Using Java How can I import/read a txt file into java and create strings from those objects

Tags: java

I have a txt file and I need to import/read the names and grades and sort the names alphabetically.

Example of txt file:

```
John Doe, 30, 25, 70, 10
Jane Doe, 33, 20, 80, 15
Christian Pulisic, 70, 60, 50, 20
```

I am reading the txt file below but how can I pull out the names and grades into separate strings/int objects? I will most likely create a separate Student class.

````
package project;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
            // pass the path to the file as a parameter
            File file = new File("Filepath);
           
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            scan.useDelimiter(",");
            
         
        // Read data from a file
        String fileData = " ";
        
        Student[] student = new Student[20];
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String firstName = scan.next();
            
          System.out.print(firstName);
        }

        // Close the file
        scan.close();
      }

```
`
````

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach so far. I would hold the grades in an array

Comment: You can use the `String.split(...)` method to split each line into an array. You can then use the `String.trim()` method to remove leading/trailing spaces. Then you can use the values from the array to create your Student class. You can use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the string values to int.

Comment: @camickr no split is necessary as the `Scanner` already is using the correct delimiter. It simply needs to consume the correct data types in succession

Comment: @g00se, *It simply needs to consume the correct data types in succession* - I got a NoSuchElementException when I tried to add all 5 scan.next() statement inside the loop. The delimiter doesn't include the end-of-line string so the 5th token wraps to the next line and includes the name as part of the token, so you run out of tokens. Logically I also think it is more understandable to read a single line of data and then parse the data into its 5 pieces instead of trying to read 5 tokens and combine then back into a single Student class.

Comment: Actually the data posted look like they  don't include line separators ( or *did* when I first looked). If for some reason no not do that can easily be corrected with delimiter `"\\R,"`

Comment: @g00se *the data posted look like they don't include line separators* - the OP posted data on separate lines, but the site displays the data on one line unless the original formatting is retained. A "," was not included after the last number on each line. I edited the question to provide proper formatting to make the question clearer.

Comment: @g00se *can easily be corrected with delimiter "\\R,"* - Still got the Exception. I'm not a regex person but don't you need some kind of "or" condition? I also tried just using "\\r" to see if I could tokenize each line but I still got an Exception.  Also, would this approach work on Windows where "\r\n" is used as the new line string?

Comment: Sorry, that was woolly. I meant `"\\R|\\s*,\\s*"`. That's platform-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

```
scan.useDelimiter(",");
```

First of all, the delimiter should be ", " since you have a space after each comma.

Another problem is that you have two conditions to find a token:

1. ", " - for the token on each line
2. "\\R" - to handle the last token at the end of each line

So, you could change the delimiter:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StudentData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("main.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( file );
        scan.useDelimiter("\\R|, ");

        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            String name = scan.next();
            int mark1 = scan.nextInt();
            int mark2 = scan.nextInt();
            int mark3 = scan.nextInt();
            int mark4 = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println(name + " : " + mark1 + " : " + mark2 + " : " + mark3 + " : " + mark4);
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

This approach is very flexible for your file format:

1. keep all the student data on a single line.
2. have each piece of data on a separate line. So, each student would be 5 lines of data.

However, because of this flexibility it is harder to verify the format to make sure each student only has exactly 5 pieces of data.

A slightly different approach would be to use the `Scanner` to read each line and then use the `String.split(...)` to tokenize the line.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StudentData2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("main.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( file );
        scan.useDelimiter("\\R");

        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            String[] tokens = scan.next().split(", ");

            if (tokens.length == 5)
            {
                String name = tokens[0];
                int mark1 = Integer.parseInt( tokens[1] );
                int mark2 = Integer.parseInt( tokens[2] );
                int mark3 = Integer.parseInt( tokens[3] );
                int mark4 = Integer.parseInt( tokens[4] );

                System.out.println(name + " : " + mark1 + " : " + mark2 + " : " + mark3 + " : " + mark4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to do a simple check to make sure each line contains all the student data. Further checks can be added to make sure is token is a valid format.